# Market Watch NewsFeed for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, intranet, script

Currently working on an Intranet site. I want to add an app or script or newsfeed that provides stock market data updates on an SharePoint Intranet site. An example is from MarketWatch as shown in the picture. Any suggestions on that?

[image]

Comment: Hi Robert, do you a reason why you have put the question on hold?

Comment: The reason is in the help text above, your question is way to broad to be able to be answered in a few paragraphs. You should add more details to your question to narrow it, so that it is answerable

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You added a picture yes, but how do you want to create this app? Do you have any technologies you master, or do you want an app from the store etc?

Comment: To be precise, am talking about rss feed to look like that picture